# what the difference between ASP.NET, ASP webforms and ASP MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I wish to produce a contact form on a website and was looking to use C# and ASP.NET. What version of ASP.NET should I use. I do not know the difference between them all. I have already created the form through HTML and CSS and need to add some validation.

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to ask such thing on SO. I would simply use webforms though (=ASP.NET as abuse of language)

Comment: Steve this is really a personal research question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both WebForms and MVC are built on ASP.NET.  ASP.NET is the basic .NET framework library for web applications.  There are three derived frameworks that Microsoft provides, WebForms, MVC, and Web Pages (using WebMatrix).  There are also a number of third party frameworks built on MVC, such as fubuMVC and Nancy.

There are already many questions on Stack Overflow asking about the difference between these, I suggest you search on them.

However, if all you need is validation, you don't need any of these, as you can use jQuery validation directly with static HTML pages.